# Rsyslog producing errors when trying to write to mounted drive

Tags: mount, rsyslog, azure

Could anyone take a look at this and see if I've done something obviously wrong?

I am running RockyLinux and attempting to setup a syslog server.
Its running with an Azure VM with an additional 2TB datadrive attached.

I have mounted the drive in Rocky and amended `fstab`, confirming its presence upon reboot, and I can write to it.

Rsyslog is all setup and configured and works fine if I leave the default settings and allow logs to be sent to /var/log but as soon as I point it to my datadrive I get permission errors.

```
May 24 11:30:20 MyServer rsyslogd[4315]: error during config processing: Could not open dynamic file '/datadrive/syslogs/MyServer/rsyslogd.log' [state -3000] - discarding message [v8>
May 24 11:30:20 MyServer rsyslogd[4315]: error during config processing: omfile: creating parent directories for file  '/datadrive/syslogs/MyServer/rsyslogd.log' failed: Permission denied

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.6G  148M  1.4G  10% /run
/dev/sda3       7.9G  1.8G  6.1G  23% /
/dev/sda2       994M  430M  564M  44% /boot
/dev/sda1       100M  7.0M   93M   7% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb1        16G   28K   15G   1% /mnt
tmpfs           769M     0  769M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdc1       2.0T   15G  2.0T   1% /datadrive
```

And the two directories have the same permissions and owners

```
[myroot@MyServer log]$ pwd
/var/log
.......
drwx------.  2 root   root     31 May 24 11:09 remote-device


[myroot@MyServer /]$ pwd
/
.....    
drwx------.   3 root root   21 May 24 10:03 datadrive
```

The only thing I have noticed is that when I try to enter the data drive `cd /datadrive` and `sudo cd /datadrive` is not working, I have to issue `sudo su` before changing directory to /datadrive

Could this be what is causing the issue? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is ACL, probably controlled by AppArmor.

Firstly, though, for the benefit of anyone else reading this answer in the future, your log permissions are non-standard. It is not normal to run logging as `root` - usually this would happen under the `syslog` user, which is part of the `adm` group. Therefore, to prepare a custom log location, you would usually ensure that the desired directory is writeable by the `syslog` group. You can personally skip the `chgrp` and `chmod` commands below if you want to continue using `root`, but other people will need them.

#### 1. Configuration

Update `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.rsyslogd` and add the second line here under the first:

```
  /var/log/**                   rw,
  /datadrive/**                 rw,
```

The first line is the default location, which will already exist in your config file. The second line is your datadrive mount point. Other readers should modify this location to suit.

#### 2. Commands

Run:

```bash
sudo chgrp syslog /datadrive/
sudo chmod g+w /datadrive/

sudo systemctl restart apparmor.service
sudo systemctl restart rsyslog.service
```

The first command will change the group ownership of the datadrive log location to `syslog`, which is standard, and the second command will allow that group to write to that directory (which includes creating files and subdirectories). You can personally skip these two commands if you continue to use `root`, but as mentioned, other users with a standard setup will need them.

We then restart AppArmor, to pick up the config changes, and then rsyslogd.

You should now be able to verify success by running `sudo systemctl status rsyslog`, and indeed by checking that data is being added to the `/datadrive` location.

#### Additional

For reference, this will completely reset the ownership and permissions to the normal defaults, i.e. a total change rather than the specific surgical change listed above:

```bash
sudo chown root:syslog /datadrive/
sudo chmod 775 /datadrive/
```

And, it is *possible* (but unlikely) that you may need to run something along these lines to specifically control ACL - but as Rocky Linux appears to use AppArmor, that is the most likely culprit:

```bash
sudo setfacl -m user:syslog:rwx /datadrive/
```

Note, I am not a Rocky Linux user, but these are the steps I had to follow on Ubuntu/Debian, so I expect the cause and resolution to be the same, due to both using AppArmor.

As a broader observation, it is always worth checking AppArmor restrictions for any standard system services if you modify file locations, as a system with AppArmor in place will usually define tight security controls for such processes.